# Filtering of result according to maximum date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

following is my sql query in which i am trying to filter the result as per dates (Greater than) difference. The SQL function "Date(FROM_UNIXTIME(i_last_updated))" returns the dates successfully but the following query is not filtering the results as per where clause check. Kindly let me know is there something wrong with my sql query and how can i correct that. Thank you

NOTE: "I successfully did it by using simple if/else but i want to know is there any possible way to do it with sql query"

```
$d= "2012-12-25"

$sql2 = "SELECT attendees FROM event_attendees where Date(FROM_UNIXTIME(i_last_updated)) > $d";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `'` around the date variable:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT attendees FROM event_attendees where Date(FROM_UNIXTIME(i_last_updated)) > '$d'";
```

Comment: oops thank you very much "i hate when i make such foolish mistakes"

Answer (score 0):

Look up the MySQL `datediff` function, which will allow you to compare the result of `FROM_UNIXTIME()` with `$d`.  Test for the sign of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use MySQL's [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function to find the difference between two dates.

OR

To me however it seems that instead of converting the `i_last_updated` for each row it would be better to convert `$d` into unix timestamp. You can do that using MySQL's [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function.